# Is there a built-in function (or other method) to iterate over a list while the elements <= limit?

Tags: python, python-2.7, iterator

I would like to be able to iterate over a list while the elements are less than or equal to a certain limit. I have made a function myself that produces the results I want, but I was wondering if there was a function that does this for me, or if the result can be reproduced with something like list comprehension so I don't have to make a separate function call? Basically, I am wondering if there is a shorter/faster way to iterate like this, since I need to use it in multiple python files and for large iterations.

I have looked through python 2.7's itertools documentation https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html which I thought would have what I was looking for (it might have and I missed it, since I don't understand a couple of the functions in itertools).

Here is an example of what I have and the results I want:

```
def iterList(iList, limit):
    index = 0
    while index < len(iList) and iList[index] <= limit:
        yield iList[index]
        index += 1

primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
smallPrimes = list()
for p in iterList(primes, 19):
    smallPrimes.append(p)

print smallPrimes
# now smallPrimes == [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19]
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use [`itertools.takewhile()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):

```
from itertools import takewhile

for p in takewhile(lambda i: i < 20, primes):
```

`takewhile` iterates until the predicate is no longer true.

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import takewhile
>>> primes = [2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 31, 37, 41, 43, 47]
>>> for p in takewhile(lambda i: i < 20, primes):
...     print p
... 
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
19
```

Comment: Your answers are always perfect.How is that possible ?

Comment: I knew it had to be in itertools and I haven't used takewhile before. I didn't think about the possibility of passing a conditional via lambda, which will save me lots of time. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

you're searching for [takewhile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.takewhile):
It makes an iterator that yield elements as long as the predicate is true.

```
takewhile(lambda x: x<5, [1,4,6,4,1]) # --> 1 4
```